# Error trying to install python-firebase on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, python

[image: This is a screenshot from a terminal on my Raspberry Pi 3.]

I have installed `requests` but I'm unable to install the python-firebase package.

I want to fetch data from firebase on my Raspberry Pi 3. I have used the following code to do the same on my PC.

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = firebase.get('/messages', None)
print (result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberrypi. With what command did you install `request`. With: `sudo pip install requests==1.1.0` ?

Comment: Yes. I used the same.

Comment: If you can, it'd be great to transcribe or copy and paste the error log from your terminal; that way, future people searching can find this question more easily and hopefully get a solution faster.

Comment: pypi says it requires requests==1.1.0 but the Git does not specify version [Firebase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your error is coming from pip. I'd recommend to `apt-get remove pip` and then `easy_install pip`.

Comment: This would seem likely to be the issue. The root cause is explored on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341847/6650102) — *"This problem is caused by a mismatch between your pip installation and your requests installation. As of requests version 2.4.0 requests.compat.IncompleteRead has been removed. Older versions of pip, e.g. from July 2014, still relied on IncompleteRead. In the current version of pip, the import of IncompleteRead has been removed."*